# Comparing scores and checking the results correspond to the correct player

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to create a league table that checks scores stored in a different table and can use the IF logic to give either a 1 or 0 under a specific heading (wins or losses).

The problem is that I need the logic to compare the scores and determine the biggest, but then to check if the name in the results table is the same as the name given as having achieved that score.

In the table below for example, Julia beat Stephan 1 - 0 and Luke 2 - 0, I need a formula that checks if the name Julia is on the same row in the results table before changing it.

[image: Example]

I am thinking it will be something like SUMIF in combination with IF, but I'm struggling to get the result I'm looking for.

Below is the results table, so for example if "Luke and Katrin" was replaced by another name or if Katrin had won, the results table would be updated from a formula and the table would automatically change in order of most points/best goal difference.

[image: Example]

Comment: Please share desired output too, currently it's difficult to understand your question.

Comment: I would add a winner column that would have the winners name in it, Then do a table that counts how many times each name appears in that column. Although if you could add pictures of how you would expect it to look, that might help, as I'm unsure if this is what you want

Comment: The desired output is that no matter if the names are changed around or the scores changed, the results table will always count a win, loss or draw to the correct row, with the correct name. I have added how the result table looks to my original question.